# IIS6 cannot handle WCF json response

Tags: wcf, json, iis-6

I wonder if you could help me with this. I have a .NET 3.5 WCF RESTful service that returns json. Service works fine on my local machine but when I deploy it on IIS6 I get this error: The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

The WebInvoke method is GET and when I try to access the service method in browser on the IIS6 machine I get a prompt that asks me to download a file (with the response of the GET request).

I'm really baffled by this as when I choose to download and open the file I see the json that is suppossed to be returned....Strange behavior by IIS.

Any clues on this?

Comment: Download fiddler and look at the difference between the request that your browser is making (that works) and the request that the app makes.  There must be something different between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was rather trivial...
Because my wcf operation was returning a List of objects for some reason IIS insists in that case the BodyStyle to be *WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped* , unlike local development service where the response was returned correctly both with Bare and Wrapped formats.
Thanks for all suggestions guys.

Comment: Wow! That sounds like a gotcha for my notes. Thank YOU!